Means for verifying files copied from PC to Android
I want to verify that the files copied from PC to Android device were copied properly. Between Windows machines, I could use Multipar program to create a par file which I can use to verify the files after they are copied. I would run the files and see if everything is okay. Is there any tool that serves the same purpose for Android devices or can use the par file. I tried looking up MutiPar for Android and could not find anything.
I am looking for a program that allows me to create a list of hashes from files in a directory on Android, and be able to use that list against PC directories.
Thank you.

Use Termux terminal in combination with e.g. md5sum command. Then loop it and append file names and hashes to a file.

Not an easy solution. Was looking for something simpler. Thanks anyway.

Some random file managers could have checksum checking built-in, but there are so many that ¯_(ツ)_/¯ I doubt too many will allow exporting that data though.
